# How to isolate Python 2.7.X on Ubuntu 12.04 which has default Python 2.7.3?

Tags: 12.04, python

I want to build Python 2.7.8 on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine, which has Python 2.7.3 as default distribution. I would like to "install" Python 2.7.8 but isolate it completely from Python 2.7.3 - meaning, I don't want to interfere at all with the distribution's default Python, including modules installed via apt-get or PIP.

I would like to do this from source, and I would like not to use virtualenv - I'd rather learn to do it the "hard" way before using more sophisticated tools.

A second related part to this question is, after I have installed Python 2.7.8, how can I have two different PIPs, the default installing Python modules to Python 2.7.3, and the alternative installing modules to Python 2.7.8?

Thanks.

Comment: The distinction that makes me think this isn't a duplicate is the second part of the question, which differs from the question cited by the additional requirement of total isolation from the installation (i.e. also modules). If I were talking about 3.0 vs 2.7.3 that would be one thing, but, for example, if I wanted to install 2.7.3, 2.7.5 and 2.7.8 I'm not sure I could with the method proposed. I am a newbie at this so I could be totally wrong...

Comment: @bodhi.zazen edited to try to clarify distinction from possible duplicate

Answer (score 2):

First, to make sure I started with a clean slate, I took the following steps:

- Uninstalled package `xlwt` (for testing), via `sudo apt-get uninstall python-xlwt` and `pip uninstall xlwt`
- Uninstalled PIP via `sudo apt-get uninstall python-pip`
- Made clean python source directory (~/src/Python2.7.8) via `make clean`
- Made sure pip was not available via `which pip` (resulted in nothing)

To build Python 2.7.X and make sure PIP is configured for only that specific installation

- (assuming already downloaded and decompressed into home directory, say `~/src/Python2.7.8`)
- Make two directories for `--prefix` and `--exec-prefix` configure options, say `~/bld/python2.7.8_ind` and `~/bld/python2.7.8_dep`
- Go to source directory (e.g. ~/src/Python2.7.8) and type

  ```
  ./configure --prefix=/home/uname/bld/python2.7.8_ind --exec-prefix=/home/uname/bld/python2.7.8_dep
  ```
- type `make && make install`

The binary `python` (or a symbolic link to the binary) for this installation is located in this example in `/home/uname/bld/python2.7.8_dep/bin`

- Use this binary to install pip from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py by typing
  `~/bld/python2.7.8_dep/bin/python get-pip.py`

This creates a (previously non-extant) directory `bin` in `~/bld/python2.7.8_ind` and places the PIP executables there which will be used for this specific installation. The PIP packages are placed in `~/bld/python2.7.8_ind/lib/python2.7/site-packages` (which was previously empty save a README file).

Now, to install the first package to this specific python installation,

I verified that the directory `~/bld/python2.7.8_ind/lib/python2.7/site-packages` contains only packages added during PIP installation (pip, setuptools, easy_install)

- type `~/bld/python2.7.8_dep/bin/pip install xlwt`

Now, the directory `~/bld/python2.7.8_ind/lib/python2.7/site-packages` contains a new package (xlwt).

Now when I type

```
~/bld/python2.7.8_dep/bin/python
>>> import xlwt
```

it works, and typing `python` and `import xlwt` produces an error (as expected). Also verify that path searched for packages by new python installation is correct with

```
~/bld/python2.7.8_dep/bin/python
>>> import site
>>> site.getsitepackages()
```

This whole process might have been obvious to non-newbies, but I'm a newbie so I've written it all out.

Answer (score 0):

Install it into /usr/local

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/` contains `dist-packages` which has been modified by PIP with python 2.7.3 and `site-packages` which may have other modules in it intended to be used with 2.7.3. How can I make sure that python 2.7.8 has its own modules? In other words, `/usr/local/lib/python2.7.8` would be ideal if I could make a second PIP installation work with it.

Comment: @jpf tried setting PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @muru I haven't set PYTHONPATH but according to the documentation the default search path for the standard Python libraries is always appended to PYTHONPATH; i.e. PYTHONPATH _augments_ the default search path - it doesn't completely isolate the two installations. PYTHONHOME might be more relevant to what I'm trying to do, but before I use PYTHONHOME I need to know how to install any number of additional python2.7 default libraries to a directory different from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` (via PIP) and `/usr/lib/python2.7` (see https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html).